# File/folder access APIs for Office365?

Tags: web-services, office-365

I would like to access files/folders stored in an Office365 account, both read/write.

What are the APIs I can use to do this?
I am OK with modifying Office365 settings, or adding plugins to Office365 if that is even possible.

Bonus for APIs that are open standards (approved by ISO, W3C, OASIS, or similar).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Office 365 API that is currently in preview: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605893(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605893%28v=office.15%29.aspx), it is REST and OAuth